# Sum rows based on name after groupby - SQL redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

> select Column A, sum(Column B)
>
> from table
>
> group by Column A

After groupby I got the following table with 2 columns, name and price

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 999 |
| Bike | 500 |
| Motorbike red | 1000 |
| Motorbike blue | 1500 |

I need to merge those rows that start with the word Motorbike, the result should be this one

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 999 |
| Bike | 500 |
| Motorbikes | 2500 |

I know i can filter those rows with something like **left(Column A,9) = 'Motorbike'** but do not know how to do the merge and if i have to do it before the group by, in the select clause, or after group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate on a `CASE` expression which buckets together all motorbike column A values:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ColumnA LIKE 'Motorbike%' THEN 'Motorbikes' ELSE ColumnA END AS ColumnA,
    SUM(Column B)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ColumnA LIKE 'Motorbike%' THEN 'Motorbikes' ELSE ColumnA END;
```

Comment: Thanks!

When i run the query i get the name "Motorbikes" for each 1000 and 1500 price row, group by is not grouping but the name changed to "Motorbikes"